# Types accepted as parameters for scikit-learn.predict methods

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I am working on a project where I am using a machine learning algorithm (namely the scikit-learn RandomForestClassifier class) to classify some data. I have already used `RandomForestClassifier.fit()` to fit the training data and now I am trying to use it to predict my data.

My problem is I'm not sure what type of data I need to be passing into my `RandomForestClassifier.predict()` method to make a prediction. I have already used the `predict()` method to predict using a test set, but I am struggling to see how to apply my trained algorithm for more general use problems.

Namely my main issue is I am trying to make a prediction for a single row of my dataframe. locate a single row in the dataframe I used to train the algorithm and make a single prediction for it. This is one of many variations of the code I've used:

```
Xnew = productMarketResearch.loc[50]
    Xnew = np.array(Xnew.values.tolist())
    Xnew = sc.transform(Xnew)
    ynew = rfc.predict(Xnew)
```

Everything I try throws the same error:

```
ValueError: Expected 2D array, got 1D array instead:
array=[3.63360000e+04 1.55639455e+12 0.00000000e+00].
Reshape your data either using array.reshape(-1, 1) if your data has a single feature or array.reshape(1, -1) if it contains a single sample.
```

I have tried using array.reshape among other methods for converting this to a 2D array but nothing has worked. Any solutions for this problem as well as some general advice for using the `predict()` method alongside dataframes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most of sklearn models require 2D array. Try:

```
# difference here
Xnew = productMarketResearch.loc[[50]]
# usually you don't need this
# Xnew = np.array(Xnew.values.tolist())

Xnew = sc.transform(Xnew)
ynew = rfc.predict(Xnew)
```

Comment: that works a treat, thank you! I had no idea it was as simple as just putting another pair of brackets...